# a pagination system from an array of arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, pagination

i am currently working on a hourly forecast, the original array has 168 hours in it. While successfully dividing that large array into 14 smaller arrays I am trying to figure out how to make a pagination system with a load more button. Appreciate any help to clean up this code while keeping all the functionality of it.

```js
 function renderHourlyWeather(hourly) {
  hourlySection.innerHTML = "";

  const smallArrays = splitHours(hourly, 12);
  //first page
  smallArrays[0].forEach(hour => {
    const hourRowElement = hourRowTemplate.content.cloneNode(true);
    setValue("day", DAY_FORMATTER.format(hour.timestamp), { parent: hourRowElement});
    setValue("time",HOUR_FORMATTER.format(hour.timestamp) , { parent: hourRowElement});
    hourRowElement.querySelector("[data-icon]").src = getIconUrl(hour.iconCode);
    const tempButton = hourRowElement.querySelector("button");
    const tempOnly = hourRowElement.querySelector(".temp-only");
    if (hour.chanceOfPrecip > 0) {
      setValue("temp", hour.temp, { parent: hourRowElement });
      tempButton.classList.remove("hidden");
    } else {
      setValue("temp-no-precip", hour.temp, { parent: hourRowElement });
      tempOnly.classList.remove("hidden");
    }
    setValue("temp", hour.temp, { parent: hourRowElement });
    setValue("precip-percent", hour.chanceOfPrecip, { parent: hourRowElement });
    setValue("fl-temp", hour.feelsLike, { parent: hourRowElement });
    setValue("wind", hour.windSpeed, { parent: hourRowElement});
    setValue("precip-amount", hour.precipAmount, { parent: hourRowElement });
    setValue("humidity", hour.humidity, { parent: hourRowElement });
    setValue("dew-point", hour.dewPoint, { parent: hourRowElement }); 
    hourlySection.append(hourRowElement);
  });
  tableRowInteractive();
  console.log(smallArrays);
  const loadMoreBtn = document.querySelector(".load-more");
  loadMoreBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {

    smallArrays[1].forEach(hour => {
      const hourRowElement = hourRowTemplate.content.cloneNode(true);
      setValue("day", DAY_FORMATTER.format(hour.timestamp), { parent: hourRowElement});
      setValue("time",HOUR_FORMATTER.format(hour.timestamp) , { parent: hourRowElement});
      hourRowElement.querySelector("[data-icon]").src = getIconUrl(hour.iconCode);
      const tempButton = hourRowElement.querySelector("button");
      const tempOnly = hourRowElement.querySelector(".temp-only");
      if (hour.chanceOfPrecip > 0) {
        setValue("temp", hour.temp, { parent: hourRowElement });
        tempButton.classList.remove("hidden");
      } else {
        setValue("temp-no-precip", hour.temp, { parent: hourRowElement });
        tempOnly.classList.remove("hidden");
      }
      setValue("temp", hour.temp, { parent: hourRowElement });
      setValue("precip-percent", hour.chanceOfPrecip, { parent: hourRowElement });
      setValue("fl-temp", hour.feelsLike, { parent: hourRowElement });
      setValue("wind", hour.windSpeed, { parent: hourRowElement});
      setValue("precip-amount", hour.precipAmount, { parent: hourRowElement });
      setValue("humidity", hour.humidity, { parent: hourRowElement });
      setValue("dew-point", hour.dewPoint, { parent: hourRowElement }); 
      hourlySection.append(hourRowElement);
    });
    tableRowInteractive();

    //alert("Loading");
  });


  function tableRowInteractive() {

    const table = document.querySelector('.hour-section');
    for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
      const group = row.querySelectorAll('.temp-percent');
      const group2 = row.querySelectorAll('.dew-humidity-group-tr');
  
      group.forEach(element => {
        element.addEventListener("click", () => {
              toggleGroup(group[0], group[1])
        });
        const percentage = row.querySelector("[data-precip-percent]").innerHTML;
        if (percentage > 80) {
          element.classList.add("high");
        }
        else if(percentage > 50) {
          element.classList.add("medium");
        } 
        else if(percentage >= 20) {
          element.classList.add("low");
        } 
      })
      
      group2.forEach(element => {
        element.addEventListener("click", () => {
             toggleGroup(group2[0], group2[1])
        }
        );
        
        const label = element.querySelector(".label");
        const dewPointNumber = row.querySelector('[data-dew-point]').innerHTML;
  
        if (dewPointNumber >= 70) {
          label.classList.add("bad"); 
        }
        else if (dewPointNumber > 60) {
          label.classList.add("normal");
        }
        else if (dewPointNumber > 50) {
          label.classList.add("good");
        }
        else if (dewPointNumber < 50) {
          label.classList.add("best");
        }
  
      })
    }
  }

  // split hours into small chunks

  function splitHours(hourArray, chunkSize) {
    const results = [];
    let index = 0;
    while (index < hourArray.length) {
      results.push(hourArray.slice(index, index + chunkSize));
      index += chunkSize;
    }
    return results;
  }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function renderHourlyWeather(hourly) {
  hourlySection.innerHTML = "";

  const smallArrays = splitHours(hourly, 12);
  //first page
  appendRows(smallArrays[0]);

  console.log(smallArrays.length);
  const loadMoreBtn = document.querySelector(".load-more");
  // Pagination System 
  var index = 1;
  loadMoreBtn.addEventListener("click", () => {
    if (index < smallArrays.length) { 
      appendRows(smallArrays[index]);
      index++;
    } else {
      loadMoreBtn.classList.add("hidden");
    }
    //alert("Loading");
  });


  function appendRows(array) {
    array.forEach(hour => {
      const hourRowElement = hourRowTemplate.content.cloneNode(true);
      setValue("day", DAY_FORMATTER.format(hour.timestamp), { parent: hourRowElement});
      setValue("time",HOUR_FORMATTER.format(hour.timestamp) , { parent: hourRowElement});
      hourRowElement.querySelector("[data-icon]").src = getIconUrl(hour.iconCode);
      const tempButton = hourRowElement.querySelector("button");
      const tempOnly = hourRowElement.querySelector(".temp-only");
      if (hour.chanceOfPrecip > 0) {
        setValue("temp", hour.temp, { parent: hourRowElement });
        tempButton.classList.remove("hidden");
      } else {
        setValue("temp-no-precip", hour.temp, { parent: hourRowElement });
        tempOnly.classList.remove("hidden");
      }
      setValue("temp", hour.temp, { parent: hourRowElement });
      setValue("precip-percent", hour.chanceOfPrecip, { parent: hourRowElement });
      setValue("fl-temp", hour.feelsLike, { parent: hourRowElement });
      setValue("wind", hour.windSpeed, { parent: hourRowElement});
      setValue("precip-amount", hour.precipAmount, { parent: hourRowElement });
      setValue("humidity", hour.humidity, { parent: hourRowElement });
      setValue("dew-point", hour.dewPoint, { parent: hourRowElement }); 
      hourlySection.append(hourRowElement);
    });
    tableRowInteractive();
  }
  function tableRowInteractive() {
    
    const table = document.querySelector('.hour-section');
    for (var i = 0, row; row = table.rows[i]; i++) {
      const group = row.querySelectorAll('.temp-percent');
      const group2 = row.querySelectorAll('.dew-humidity-group-tr');
  
      group.forEach(element => {
        element.addEventListener("click", () => {
              toggleGroup(group[0], group[1])
        });
        const percentage = row.querySelector("[data-precip-percent]").innerHTML;
        if (percentage > 80) {
          element.classList.add("high");
        }
        else if(percentage > 50) {
          element.classList.add("medium");
        } 
        else if(percentage >= 20) {
          element.classList.add("low");
        } 
      })
      
      group2.forEach(element => {
        element.addEventListener("click", () => {
             toggleGroup(group2[0], group2[1])
        }
        );
        
        const label = element.querySelector(".label");
        const dewPointNumber = row.querySelector('[data-dew-point]').innerHTML;
  
        if (dewPointNumber >= 70) {
          label.classList.add("bad"); 
        }
        else if (dewPointNumber > 60) {
          label.classList.add("normal");
        }
        else if (dewPointNumber > 50) {
          label.classList.add("good");
        }
        else if (dewPointNumber < 50) {
          label.classList.add("best");
        }
  
      })
    }
  }
  // split hours into small chunks

  function splitHours(hourArray, chunkSize) {
    const results = [];
    let index = 0;
    while (index < hourArray.length) {
      results.push(hourArray.slice(index, index + chunkSize));
      index += chunkSize;
    }
    return results;
  }  
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).